# Function to convert string to numeric datatype and round float values

Tags: python

I wrote a function to convert string to numeric data types. Although it is working but I am not impressed with the code and need to clean it up.

```
def str_to_numeric(str_list):
        """
        modify elements of list received from file to numeric data
        type.

        """
        temp_list = []
        for item in str_list:
            if type(item) == str:
                try:
                    temp_list.append(int(item))
                except:
                    temp_list.append(round(float(item), 1))
            elif type(item) == float:
                temp_list.append(round(float(item), 1))
            else:
                temp_list.append(item)

        str_list = temp_list
        return str_list

List1 = ['1.0005','1.56666', 1, '1.2333', '1']

List1 = str_to_numeric(List1)
Output: [1.0, 1.6, 1, 1.2, 1]
```

I am getting the expected output but I want a few changes:

1. I don't want to use temp_list and want to perform computation on the same list something like:
       item = int(item)
2. I want a list to update when I call str_to_numeric(List1) not List1 = str_to_numeric(List1)

Is it possible?

Comment: Any reason you can't use numpy?? it could look as simple as: `numpy.array(List1).astype('float')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> def str_to_numeric(str_list):
        """
        modify elements of list received from file to numeric data
        type.

        """
        for i,item in enumerate(_ for _ in str_list):
            if type(item) == str:
                try:
                    str_list[i] = int(item)
                except:
                    str_list[i]=round(float(item), 1)
            elif type(item) == float:
                str_list[i] = round(float(item), 1)
            else:
                str_list[i]=item
>>> List1 = ['1.0005','1.56666', 1, '1.2333', '1']
>>> str_to_numeric(List1)
>>> List1
[1.0, 1.6, 1, 1.2, 1]
```

works. remember that if you pass a list into a function, it passes in its reference, so changing it in the function is changing the actual list

Comment: Why are you testing if the type of the item is a string?  If it cannot be cast as a float or an int, this will come out naturally as an error.  EAFP.

Comment: Yes, but this is your chance to show a more Pythonic answer.  The OP began by asking for help with cleaner code.  This function can be half the length.

Comment: you never know what he intended with his initial code and whether this is more to it than he posted. who knows, what if his list might somehow contain something that is not a string, int, or float? if one of the list items was, say, another list, then he could handle that in the else statement. regardless, he had two questions and i answered them and it worked. why be nitpicky?

Comment: If there's a non-number-like item in the list, it's not going to end up being a list of numbers.  Nitpicky would be asking if your shift key is broken; I'm just trying to help you give the best answer possible.

Comment: I never said it would, nor do I expect it to with this code, but it will still accept the item and put it into the list as whatever it was. Speaking of best answer possible, try passing in a list as one of the items using your code. will it crash?

Comment: It will throw an error, exactly as intended.  That's the core of EAFP programming.  Leaving an item in there that can't become a number will just propagate the error downstream when trying to use the output.

Comment: actually try doing it and see if it will crash or not. i have a feeling that calling `round` on a list object will not bode well.

Comment: You're not reading the code, then, because round will never be called on a list object (that is a TypeError, not a ValueError).  As I said, passing a list to make_numeric() will throw an error, exactly as intended.  You don't want that to pass silently.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where you would benefit by breaking up your code into more logical pieces.  Your core task revolves around performing a specific action on various things that could be numbers, so it would make sense to put that in its own function.  You might also have use for that on its own.  Also, you have overly complicated the testing; there is no need to test if the input is a string.  Consider the following:

```
def make_numeric(thing, precision=1):
    try:
        return int(thing)
    except ValueError:
        return round(float(thing), precision)


def str_to_numeric(str_list):
    for i in range(len(str_list)):
        str_list[i] = make_numeric(str_list[i])


>>> k = ['1.0005','1.56666', 1, '1.2333', '1']
>>> str_to_numeric(k)
>>> k
[1.0, 1.6, 1, 1.2, 1]
```